# Prolog y hechos en la base de datos

Tags: prolog, árboles-binarios, árboles

Buenas, estoy aprendiendo prolog y tengo algunas preguntas para vosotros. Me interesa saber más el **cómo** se hacen estos problemas más que la respuesta final ya que mi intención es aprender y no resolver el ejercicio directamente.

Mi pregunta es

Tengo un árbol binario definido de la siguiente manera

```
arbol(Id, R, HI, HD)
```

Por ejemplo, el siguiente árbol

[image]

Se define de la siguiente manera

```
arbol(a4,6,b3,b4).
arbol(b3,7,c1,c2).
arbol(c1,5,d1,nil).
arbol(d1,1,nil,nil).
arbol(c2,3,nil,d2).
arbol(d2,4,nil,nil).
arbol(b4,8,c3,c4).
arbol(c3,10,nil,nil).
arbol(c4,11,d3,d4).
arbol(d3,9,nil,nil).
arbol(d4,2,nil,nil).
```

Estos son hechos en mi base de datos de hechos. Así que mi primera pregunta es cómo puedo identificar el padre de un nodo N en esta base de datos. Por ejemlo:

```
?-padre(3,a4,P).
P=7
?-padre(6,a4,P).
false
```

El predicado padre/3 se puede explicar como:

padre(N,Abn,P).

```
N = Nodo al cual se quiere averiguar su padre
Abn = Árbol donde se está haciendo la búsqueda. Si a4, en este caso sería el árbol completo
P = Padre del nodo N
```

He pensado en hacer uso del predicado `findall/3` pero con e me devolvería una lista cuando lo que quiero es que devuelva un nodo.

Creo que podría hacer uso de predicados como retract o asserta para ir modificando la base de datos y llegar a la solución pero no lo tengo muy claro.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario un findall para tu ejemplo, sólo con buscar el nodo como hijo derecho o hijo izquierdo es suficiente. Luego, buscar el padre y el id del árbol que tiene como raiz al nodo padre:

```
padre(Nodo, IdArbol, Padre):-
 arbol(Id, Nodo, _, _),
 arbol(IdArbol, Padre, Id,_).

padre(Nodo, IdArbol, Padre):-
 arbol(Id, Nodo, _, _),
 arbol(IdArbol, Padre, _, Id).
```